# org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "alter table departement drop foreign key XX" via JDBC Statement

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, sts

While running spring boot with h2 database and JPA i am getting below error.

`org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "alter table departement drop foreign key FKixq3xt09hgnls2vfidrwbs98n" via JDBC Statement  at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar:5.6.14.Final] at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.applySqlString(SchemaDropperImpl.java:387) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar:5.6.14.Final]`

It is caused due to below one

`Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'springdb.departement' doesn't exist`

my classes are departement  and university

this is the department class.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Departement")
public class Departement {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int idDepart;
    
    private String nomDepart;

    public int getIdDepart() {
        return idDepart;
    }
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "idUniv", nullable = false)
    private Universite universite;
```

and this is the university class.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Universite")
public class Universite {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int idUniv;
    
    private String nomUniv;
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "universite")
    private Set<Departement> departements;
```

Any help.

I tried to delete the base and re try again and again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this in application.properties : spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update